# Aggregative query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First, sorry for my english. I am modeling a railways's DB in neo4j. I want to link station in the order that are linked by railway, using the stops's table. Every stop own a "stop sequence" that unfortunately isn't like 1,2,3 (not always) but only progressive like 1,3,4,6.  I wrote this query that, for the problem described, don't work always.

```
MATCH (a:Station)-[:stop]->(c:Stops_times)-[:trip]->(z:Trips)<-[:trip]-(d:Stops_times)<-[:stop]-(b:Station)  WHERE toint(c.stop_sequence)=toint(d.stop_sequence)+1  CREATE (a)-[s:next]->(b)
```

To find the right "next" I need a query similar to this:

```
MATCH (a:Station)-[:stop]->(c:Stops_times)-[:trip]->(z:Trips)<-[:trip]-(d:Stops_times)<-[:stop]-(b:Station) WITH c as c, d as d, MIN(d.stop_sequence) as min_ WHERE min_>c.stop_sequence  CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[s:next]->(b)
```

therefore, for every stop, I have to found the minimum "stop_sequence"  between the higher ones than the "stop_sequence" of the stop of wich i want to find the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query seems to do what you want. It orders all the stops by `stop_sequence`, aggregates all the stops (still in order) for each trip, pairs up all adjoining stops for each trip, `UNWIND`s the pairs so that `MERGE` can use the paired nodes, and then uses `MERGE` to ensure that the `:next` relationship exists between all node pairs.

```
MATCH (a:Station)-[:stop]->(c:Stops_times)-[:trip]->(t:Trips)
WITH a, c, t
ORDER BY c.stop_sequence
WITH t, COLLECT(a) AS s
WITH REDUCE(x =[], i IN RANGE(1, SIZE(s)-1)| x + {a: s[i-1], b: s[i]}) AS pairs
UNWIND pairs AS p
WITH p.a AS a, p.b AS b
MERGE (a)-[n:next]->(b);
```

It works properly in 2.3.2 on my Mac (but the neo4j versions available at http://console.neo4j.org/ do not work correctly when the query gets to `MERGE`).

Comment: Thanks, your query is exactly what I need! Now I have some problem with redundancy (are linked stations that has also intermediate stations) but I think is something I can manage. You have been very kind.